# Have a wait / timeout when running selenium test suite in command prompt

Tags: selenium, command-line, command-prompt, selenium-ide

When running my test suite in Selenium IDE, the tests pass as the IDE allows for enough time (30000) to find the elements.

When running my test suite using command line, the tests fail with the Timeout error below.

I have tried adding a timeout to the command by adding the words "--timeout [60000]" to the command line, 
example:

`selenium-side-runner --timeout [60000] -c "browserName=chrome" "Desktop/SIDE with CMD/CmdWithoutInit2.side"`

I have also added "Pause" and various "waits" to the actual tests in Selenium IDE, all of which work in IDE but are null when running in Command.

> TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(css selector,
>   #select2-ProjectID-v1-container > .select2-selection__placeholder)
>       Wait timed out after 15051ms

I need a way to run the Selenium IDE (.side) test suite using command line. To do this I need CMD to give enough time for the test to find each element, like the IDE does. I am hoping there is a short few words I can add to the command itself.

Comment: Hi! Could you add the part of you code where test fails?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add --timeout 6000 to the command line.
Example, in command prompt, run test by entering

> selenium-side-runner --timeout 60000 -c "browserName=chrome" "Desktop/Name.side"

Timeout syntax does not include square bracers, can remove --debug if needed, doesn't provide useful info on actual running test only on running side-runner itself.

Comment: Unfortunately setting timeout doesn't help in my case. Did anybody see an error like that - Operation timed out! at Timeout.<anonymous> (node_modules/@seleniumhq/side-runtime/src/playback-tree/command-node.ts:139:13)